# Facebook permission - com.apple.accounts error 8

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, ios6

I need to publish status on Facebook timeline. My code consists 2 request. First for verifying email permission, second for verifying publish permission. I get successful response with permission "email" request but I get error "Publish permission error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)" in second case. Do you have any ideas where could be error? Thanks for help.

```
- (void)facebookStatus:(NSString *)identifier {
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSString *key = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"];
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey : key,
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email"]
                          };

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
     if (granted) {
         NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];

         if ([accounts count] > 0) {
             ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
             ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
             NSString *key = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"];
             NSDictionary *options = @{
                                       ACFacebookAppIdKey : key,
                                       ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"publish_stream"]
                                       };

             [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted2, NSError *error) {
                  if (granted2) {
                      NSLog(@"Publish")
                      ;                          
                  }
                  else {
                      NSLog(@"Publish permission error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      //_publishPermissionsGranted = NO;
                  }

              }];
         }
     }
     else NSLog(@"Nope");

    if (error) {
        if (error.code == 6) {
            NSLog(@"FB Account doesn't exist");
        }
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, I've got it! Options dictionary has to look like this:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                                       ACFacebookAppIdKey : key,
                                       ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                                       ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceEveryone
                                       };
```

Instead of this:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                                   ACFacebookAppIdKey : key,
                                   ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"publish_stream"]
                                   };
```

Comment: Looks like Facebook now recommends only using @"publish_stream".  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/